# update script results in errors when I try converting it from **Access** to **Oracle**

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, converters

I am trying to convert some queries to work with **Oracle** instead of **Access** but have been unsuccessful.  Am I just getting the order wrong? or using an incorrect statement.

This is the script:

```
Error starting at line : 142 in command -
UPDATE CONTROL_RECORDS 
SET EXTRACT_WORK_001.BAY_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT =  
DECODE(-1, 
SIGN(0 - COMBINED_LAYER_QTY), 0, 
DECODE(-1, 
SIGN(0 - BAY_ACTIVITY), 
(DECODE(ADJUSTED_BAY_USPD*DAY_COUNT/BAY_ACTIVITY<=CASEFLOW_USPD_MAX,1,0)), 
0), 
EXTRACT_WORK_001.BULK_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT =  
DECODE(-1, 
SIGN(0 - COMBINED_LAYER_QTY), 0, 
DECODE(-1, 
SIGN(0 - BULK_ACTIVITY), 
DECODE(ADJUSTED_BULK_USPD*DAY_COUNT/BULK_ACTIVITY<=CASEFLOW_USPD_MAX,1,0)), 
0), 
EXTRACT_WORK_001.COMBINED_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT =  
DECODE(-1, 
SIGN(0 - COMBINED_LAYER_QTY), 0, 
DECODE(ADJUSTED_COMBINED_USPD<=CASEFLOW_USPD_MAX,1,0)) 
FROM CONTROL_RECORDS, EXTRACT_WORK_001 
WHERE (CONTROL_RECORDS.LOC_ID = EXTRACT_WORK_001.LOC_ID) 
AND   ((EXTRACT_WORK_001.COMBINED_LAYER_QTY)=0) 
Error at Command Line : 148 Column : 81 Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

and this is the original Access query:

```
UPDATE CONTROL_RECORDS INNER JOIN EXTRACT_WORK_001 
    ON CONTROL_RECORDS.LOC_ID = EXTRACT_WORK_001.LOC_ID 
SET 
    EXTRACT_WORK_001.BAY_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT = IIf(combined_layer_qty>0,0,IIf(bay_activity>0,IIf(adjusted_BAY_USPD*day_count/bay_activity<=caseflow_uspd_max,1,0),0)), 
    EXTRACT_WORK_001.BULK_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT = IIf(combined_layer_qty>0,0,IIf(bulk_activity>0,IIf(adjusted_BULK_USPD*day_count/bulk_activity<=caseflow_uspd_max,1,0),0)), 
    EXTRACT_WORK_001.COMBINED_CASEFLOW_SKU_COUNT = IIf(combined_layer_qty>0,0,IIf(adjusted_COMBINED_USPD<=caseflow_uspd_max,1,0))
WHERE (((EXTRACT_WORK_001.COMBINED_LAYER_QTY)=0));
```

Please help.  I have no preference of what method or anything... just as long as it works.

Comment: You've got some mismatched parentheses.  Best that you do the digging to figure out what you're missing.

Comment: Hello, welcome to the site! This is a bad question. I recommend you read [the entire Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and head back when you have a specific, programming-related question.

Comment: That query makes me sad just to look at it. =( I will say this much: you will almost certainly have to rewrite the above entirely from scratch. Essentially, just rebuild it in Oracle. If you're new to SQL, I would recommend choosing an easier to use relational database. Oracle does not make learning easy. SQL Server or PostgreSQL would be my preferred choices.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have a choice in the matter...  I have created many scripts for oracle (I have little practice with access)  but this one is beyond by knowledge.  Yes I am learning it.  should I learn something else first, probably, but that is a luxury I do not have.

Comment: Well, the `IIF` in Access is essentially the `CASE` statement. Other than that, it looks fairly simple.

Comment: i looked at it differently thanks to you and changed the iifs to cases looking at the original.  I got it to go past it but got it stuck after the set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `case` is more akin to `iif` than `decode`. Many of your expressions can be simplified. Also, I don't think there's a straightforward syntax to update across a join in Oracle.

However, assuming that the tables have sensible primary and foreign keys defined, the following may work. If you get errors about key preserved tables, then you'll need to supply more information about your tables and relationships:

```
update (
    select
        w.bay_caseflow_sku_count,
        case when
            combined_layer_qty <= 0 and 
            bay_activity > 0 and 
            adjusted_bay_USPD * day_count <= bay_activity * caseflow_uspd_max
          then 1
          else 0
        end as new_bay,
        w.bulk_caseflow_sku_count,
        case when
            combined_layer_qty <= 0 and
            bulk_activity > 0 and
            adjusted_bulk_USPD * day_count <= bulk_activity * caseflow_uspd_max
          then 1
          else 0
        end as new_bulk,
        w.combined_caseflow_sku_count,
        case when
            combined_layer_qty <= 0 and
            adjusted_combined_USPD <= caseflow_uspd_max
          then 1
          else 0
        end as new_combined
    from
        extract_work_001 w
            inner join
        control_records c
            on c.loc_id = w.loc_id
    where 
        w.combined_layer_qty = 0
) t
set
    bay_caseflow_sku_count = new_bay,
    bulk_caseflow_sku_count = new_bulk,
    combined_caseflow_sku_count = new_combined;
```

[Example SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/60c7e/2)

Comment: received this:
SQL Error: ORA-01779: cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table

Comment: so read the whole comment, and take the action that it suggests in this case.

Comment: Thank you man.  You helped me a lot.  I was able to get it to work.  Thanks.